# Check csv file while content is created through a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file

how should I amend this piece of code, so that I can check the content of a csv file while the loop is not finished and also be able to retrieve all the data in case it breaks without using a try exception catch.

Here is a dummy example:

```
import time
import csv
with  open('test.csv', 'w') as f1: 
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(1000):
        writer.writerow([i])
        time.sleep(10)
        print('done')
```

On checking the content of `test.csv`  through cat in the terminal, the file is empty and can only be checked after the loop ends. Can someone please point me to a method I could use to check and use the content of a file while it is still being edited?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the for loop in the "with open(...):" section, it means the file is not closed until your for loop ends. That's why you can't see any change of the file before the loop ends.

If you have to check the file after each loop, you need to open the file, write a row and close the file in the for loop.

Here's a little example that is valid:

```
import time
import csv

for i in range(10):
    with  open('test.csv', 'a') as f1: 
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerow([i])
    time.sleep(1)
    print('done')
```

Comment: Note that you should use open(..., 'a') instead of 'w' because you are appending a row to the old csv file.